# i want foreach inside an array

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i want to add include foreach inside an array, how can i do that

```
<?php

    foreach($query as $row)
    {
        $cat=$row->categoery:
        $expenses=$row->expenses;

    }
```

how i can take this foreach loop inside this `$jsondata?`

i did like this

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $cat=$row->categoery:
    $expenses=$row->expenses;

    $jsonData = array
    (
        array("$cat", $expenses),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will just reinitialised `$jsonData` by doing as you did for each iteration.

```
$jsonData = array();

foreach($query as $row){
   $cat=$row->categoery:
   $expenses=$row->expenses;

   $jsonData[$cat] = $expenses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// in Your current loop value of array `$jsonData` is override for new value, so you always  get last row Value in your `$jsonData`

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $cat=$row->categoery:
    $expenses=$row->expenses;

    $jsonData = array
    (
        array("$cat", $expenses), // This Syntax of array is use to define Array  
    );
}
```

Here The Correction

```
  $jsonData = array(); // Here we define array 
    foreach($query as $row)  {
            $jsonData[trim($row->categoery)] = $row->expenses; //assign 
            $jsonData[$i] = $row->expenses; //to get expenses 
            $jsonData[$i] = $row->categoery; //to get  categoery
               $i++;
        }
    print_($jsonData) //here your array
```

Comment: $jsonData = array
(
    array("expenses", $row->expenses),; if i am taking expenses only

Answer (score 0):

```html
$arrData = array();
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $cat=$row->categoery:
    $expenses=$row->expenses;

 $arrData[$cat] = $expenses;
}

echo json_encode($arrData);
```